# How do I return CDATA content from XML using IXMLNode (delphi exception)

Tags: delphi

I have an XML document I try to extract values from using Delphi, and XMLDoc. Most parts work without problem. I use IXMLNode to select the node text. But I have one section which may contain CDATA. This always throws an exception when I try to get it.

My XML (relevant part) is similar to this

```
    <a>valuea</a>
    <b>My b value</b>
    <c>![CDATA[My cdata text goes here
It may have linefeed inside
like this
and I need to get all lines WITH linefeeds
]]>
</c>
```

My code today is something like this:

```
  var
     IDoc: IXMLDocument;
     INode: IXMLNode;
     XPathText : string;
     i         : integer;

              // From a post in Embarcadero's Delphi XML forum.
              function selectNode(xnRoot: IXmlNode; const nodePath: WideString): IXmlNode;
              var
                intfSelect : IDomNodeSelect;
                dnResult : IDomNode;
                intfDocAccess : IXmlDocumentAccess;
                doc: TXmlDocument;
              begin
                Result := nil;
                if not Assigned(xnRoot) or not Supports(xnRoot.DOMNode, IDomNodeSelect, intfSelect) then
                  Exit;
                dnResult := intfSelect.selectNode(nodePath);

                if Assigned(dnResult) then
                begin
                  if Supports(xnRoot.OwnerDocument, IXmlDocumentAccess, intfDocAccess) then
                    doc := intfDocAccess.DocumentObject
                  else
                    doc := nil;
                  Result := TXmlNode.Create(dnResult, nil, doc);
                end;
              end;
// --------------------------------------------
   begin
       IDoc:= LoadXMLDocument(edtXMLFileName.Text);
       idoc.ParseOptions := [poPreserveWhiteSpace];
       XPathText := './/path/to/c';   // as per example above, this is my CDATA

        INode := selectnode(IDoc.DocumentElement, xpathtext);

        showmessage(inode.text);  // <<< Notice: .text not .XML FAILS for XML with exception.


   end;
```

What is the correct way to

- Get the CDATA value
- ..while keeping any linefeeds
- I do not need  tag or the CDATA tag. Just content.

*EDIT*
Current state (correction): If I use the .XML value of the IXMLNode, I get the full  tag including the CDATA etc:

```
    <c>![CDATA[My cdata text goes here
It may have linefeed inside
like this
and I need to get all lines WITH linefeeds
]]>
</c>
```

but if I use the .text, delphi throws an exception.

```
"Element does not contain a single text node."
```

Someone suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/borland.public.delphi.xml/VzWuG-n4nCc) to use XMLTextReader, but I need to query here and there and can't do a forward read only.

My backup plan would be to use a separate function to just remove the XML / CDATA tag returned as above, but it's not pretty.

Comment: What exception are you getting exactly? On which line?

Comment: Remy: See above, I edited the question for clarity. I can either get the full "c" tag or get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

A CDATA node is different from a Text node. You can't use the `IXMLNode.Text` property to read the content of a CDATA node. This is [documented behavior](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.Text):

> **`Text` is intended for use nodes where the `IsTextElement` property is true.** If `IsTextElement` is false, then if the node has no children, the value of `Text` is an empty string.
>
> Setting `Text` is this case result in a node where `IsTextElement` is true.
>
> **If the node has children (other than a single DOM text node), reading or setting `Text` causes an exception.**

You need to use the [`IXMLNode.NodeValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.NodeValue) property instead, which can read both CDATA and Text content:

```
ShowMessage(INode.NodeValue);
```