# Delphi XML ChildNodes.FindNode does not work with CDATA

Tags: xml, delphi

I have an XML file from a Garmin device, where the `name` tag is not found, because it has a `CDATA` in it.

This is not standard, most XML files don't have this `CDATA`, and then `FindNode()` works normally.

If I look for `number` in the example below, it works normally.

How do I get around this?

```xml
<trk>
  <name><![CDATA[Drawn track]]></name>
  <src><![CDATA[MapToaster iOS]]></src>
  <number>433385247</number>
```

```pascal
LNode := TRKNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('name','');
if (LNode <> nil) and (LNode.IsTextElement) then
begin
  AName := LNode.Text;
  SLocalLog('(GetTracks) Name= ' + AName + '+TRKNode.ChildNodes.Count=' + IntToStr(TRKNode.ChildNodes.Count));
end;
if AName = '' then
begin
  LocalLog('(GetTracks) Name=empty, continue', d_warning);
  continue;
end;
```

**EDIT:**

The full start of the XML file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="MapToaster for iOS V3.5" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <time>2022-03-28T07:24:24.207Z</time>
  </metadata>
  <trk>
    <name><![CDATA[Drawn track]]></name>
    <src><![CDATA[MapToaster iOS]]></src>
    ...
```

**EDIT:**

The following code works:

```
function FindNodeEx(ID: string; Nodes: IXMLNodelist):IXMLNode;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  result := nil;
  for i := 0 to  Nodes.Count-1 do
  begin
    SLocalLog(i.ToString+': '+Nodes[i].NodeName);
    if Nodes[i].NodeName = 'name' then
    begin
      SLocalLog('FindNodeEx: ID found: ='+Nodes[i].Text);
      result := Nodes[i];
      if result.NodeType = TNodeType.ntCData then SLocalLog('FindNodeEx: CDATA found'); // This does not happen.
      SLocalLog('FindNodeEx: NodeType='+IntToStr(integer(result.NodeType))); // Shows as 'Element'
      exit;
    end;
  end;
  SLocalLog('FindNodeEx: ID not found: '+ID,d_warning);
end;
```

Comment: The content of an element should not affect your ability to find the element itself. `FindNode()` doesn't look at the element contents, only their names and namespaces. Do note, however, that `LNode.IsTextElement` *does* care about contents, and will return `False` if the element's content is a `CDATA` (but `LNode.Text` will happily read a `CDATA`). That said, is `TRKNode.ChildNodes.Count=3` as expected? Also, which `DOMVendor` are you using to parse the XML?

Comment: I think there may be someting wrong with the CDATA format. When I *scan* through the Nodes list, and search for 'name' I *do* find the Node, and then its 'Text' field is in fact 'name', but it then shows the NodeType as 'Element' (1). It *should* show as 'CDATA'.  So I can locate the 'name' when I scan through the list, but *not* when I use FindNode.

Comment: Regarding the 'DOMVendor', I will edit the original question and show the full headers. I am not very familiar with XML.

Comment: In this case, the `CDATA` would be a *child* node of a parent `element` node. Same with nodes holding plain text. In this case, `TRKNode` should have 3 immediate child element nodes in its `ChildNodes` list: `name` (with its own child `CDATA` node), `src` (with its own child `CDATA` node) , and `number` (with its own child `TEXT` node). `FindNode()` simply iterates the `ChildNode` list it is called on, looking at their names (and namespaces). So, if you can find the `name` element manually, `FindNode()` should also be able to find it.

Comment: Yes, FindNode should indeed find the 'name' Node, because when I go through the list, and search for the NodeName 'name' it finds it. This means, in this case it automatically detects the 'CDATA' and removes this from the final Node.Text field. But this does not happen with FindNode.

Comment: "*when I go through the list, and search for the NodeName 'name' it finds it*" - then the only possibility why `FindNode()` would not find it is if there is a namespace mismatch between what the XML uses and what your code looks for. You HAVE to take namespaces into account, especially since this XML is actually using namespaces.  "*This means, in this case it automatically detects the 'CDATA' and removes this from the final Node.Text field*" - `FindNode()` DOESN'T CARE about the `CDATA`, it is not even looking at it.

Comment: I have written a hack to get around it, see the edited question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243421/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-bart-kindt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XML document is using namespaces, but your use of `FindNode()` is telling it to ignore namespaces.  So, you should specify the correct namespace when calling `FindNode()`.

Also, even if `FindNode()` were successful in finding the node, the `IXMLNode.IsTextElement` property does not support `CDATA` content, only plain text content.  This is even [documented behavior](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.IsTextElement).

However, the [`IXMLNode.Text`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.Text) property will happily return `CDATA` content (which you *may or may not* have to decode manually, I'm not sure) - at least in modern versions ([older versions didn't support this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55423033/65863)).

Try something more like this:

```pascal
function IsTextOrCDataElement(const ANode: IXMLNode): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (ANode.NodeType = ntElement) and
            (ANode.DOMNode.childNodes.length = 1) and
            (ANode.DOMNode.childNodes[0].nodeType in [TEXT_NODE, CDATA_SECTION_NODE]);
end;

function RemoveCData(const AData: string): string;
begin
  if StartsText('<![CDATA[', AData) and EndsText(']]>', AData) then
    Result := Copy(AData, 10, Length(AData)-12)
  else
    Result := AData;
end;

...

LNode := TRKNode.ChildNodes.FindNode('name', 'http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1');
if (LNode <> nil) and IsTextOrCDataElement(LNode) then
begin
  AName := RemoveCData(LNode.Text);
  // or just:
  // AName := LNode.Text;
  // or:
  // AName := LNode.NodeValue;
  ...
end;
...
```